# Docker Compose: .env: no such file or directory / NodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker

Hello I'm trying to make my docker compose work, but I have the following error:

> Step 13/15 : COPY .env . COPY failed: stat
>   /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder209795817/.env: no such file or
>   directory

I'm not able to find solutions or imagine what I can do to solve this

code:

DockerCompsoe:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: emasa
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    web:
      image: emasapg
      depends_on:
        - dbs
      ports:
        - "4000:4000"
```

DockerFile:

```
FROM node as builder
WORKDIR usr/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build


FROM node
WORKDIR usr/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --production

COPY --from=builder /usr/app/dist ./dist      // I GOT PROBLEM HERE

COPY ormconfig.docker.json ./ormconfig.json
COPY .env . 

expose 4000
CMD node dist/src/index.js
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "back-end",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Awesome project developed with TypeORM.",
  "scripts": {
    "dev:server": "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpileOnly src/index.ts",
    "build": "tsc -b"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.3",
    "@types/node": "^13.9.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.11.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "graphql": "^14.6.0",
    "pg": "^7.3.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "ts-node": "^8.6.2",
    "typeorm": "0.2.24"
  }
}
```

my ormconfig:

```
{
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "db",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "postgres",
  "password": "postgres",
  "database": "emasa",
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": false,
  "entities": ["src/entity/**/*.ts"],
  "migrations": ["src/migration/**/*.ts"],
  "subscribers": ["src/subscriber/**/*.ts"],
  "cli": {
    "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
    "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
    "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
  }
}
```

and this is my folders structures:

[image: typ]

Comment: I do not see the .env file or the .dist folder in your project structure. Are these hidden by your IDE?

Comment: are not hidden I am also not understanding the reason

even me using dev: server

does not create my dist folder, even with "outDir": "./dist", in my tsconfig

Comment: I guess you need to create the .env first and add the accordant values to it.

Comment: and also if I use:

yarn tsc src / index.ts

does not create my dist folder even though it has my tsconfig

Comment: Hello this worked, could you help me because you are not creating my ./dist folder with my files in js?

Comment: Did you try `npm run build`?

Comment: work fine, can make awnser for give correct awnser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error appears because there is no .env file and no dist folder.

First of all you need to create a .env file at the root of your project structure in order to provide the needed environment variables (e.g. like name, host, port, password and user of your database connection). Next run `npm run build` to build your project, which will create the dist folder (see your tsconfig.json).

Comment: thanks @pzaenger can you help me with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60731782/docker-compose-i-cant-create-postgress-server