# Docker - Compose I can't create postgress server

Tags: node.js, docker

Hello i'm trying to create a postgres compose docker
pg admin 4
and node

but I'm having difficulties and I can't create my server:

[image]

I've tried with all possible names and I don't know what I'm wrong:

my **docker compose:**

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  emasa-postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: emasa@
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: emasa
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres-compose-network
  web:
    image: emasa-web
    depends_on:
      - emasa-postgres
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    networks:
      - postgres-compose-network
  teste-pgadmin-compose:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: "emasa@hotmail.com"
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: "emasa"
    ports:
      - "16543:80"
    depends_on:
      - emasa-postgres
    networks:
      - postgres-compose-network

networks:
  postgres-compose-network:
    driver: bridge
```

**DockerFile**:

```
FROM node as builder
WORKDIR usr/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build


FROM node
WORKDIR usr/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --production

COPY --from=builder /usr/app/dist ./dist

COPY ormconfig.docker.json ./ormconfig.json
COPY .env . 

expose 4000
CMD node dist/src/index.js
```

my orm config:

```
{
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "db",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "postgres",
  "password": "emasa@",
  "database": "postgres",
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": false,
  "entities": ["src/entity/**/*.ts"],
  "migrations": ["src/migration/**/*.ts"],
  "subscribers": ["src/subscriber/**/*.ts"],
  "cli": {
    "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
    "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
    "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
  }
}
```

my docker-compose loggers:

```
Attaching to back-end_web_1, back-end_emasa-postgres_1, back-end_teste-pgadmin-compose_1
emasa-postgres_1         | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
emasa-postgres_1         | This user must also own the server process.
emasa-postgres_1         |
emasa-postgres_1         | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
emasa-postgres_1         | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
emasa-postgres_1         | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
emasa-postgres_1         |
emasa-postgres_1         | Data page checksums are disabled.
emasa-postgres_1         |
emasa-postgres_1         | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
emasa-postgres_1         | creating subdirectories ... ok
emasa-postgres_1         | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
emasa-postgres_1         | selecting default max_connections ... 20
emasa-postgres_1         | selecting default shared_buffers ... 400kB
emasa-postgres_1         | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
emasa-postgres_1         | creating configuration files ... ok
emasa-postgres_1         | 2020-03-17 23:48:08.890 UTC [81] FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership
emasa-postgres_1         | 2020-03-17 23:48:08.890 UTC [81] HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.
emasa-postgres_1         | child process exited with exit code 1
emasa-postgres_1         | initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
emasa-postgres_1         | running bootstrap script ... web_1                    | Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db
```

my container ls:

```
docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                            NAMES
3a20bcd4f105        emasa-web           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:4000->4000/tcp           back-end_web_1
b377e650e772        dpage/pgadmin4      "/entrypoint.sh"         14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:16543->80/tcp   back-end_teste-pgadmin-compose_1
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I've really tried with the container names:

emasa-postgres_1
emasa-postgres

and to no avail

Comment: What's going wrong; is there an actual error message you're getting?  Can you trim down the code to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the issue?  `docker container ls` usually writes out text output, not a PNG file; can you replace the image with the actual output of the command?

Comment: @David Maze Hello i am getting error response on my pgadmin4 i posted the loggers on my postgress and it looks normal i will replace the image

Comment: is pgadmin up but you are just facing problem to connect to the server ?

Comment: @WaLid LamRaoui yeaah i enter on pgAdmin web but I can't create the connection

Comment: I don't know my compose is "correct"

Comment: are you using hostname : localhost and user : postgres and password : emasa@ ?

Comment: yeah i try with localhost/ docker container name and others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the problem can be seen in the log that you provided.

> 2020-03-17 23:48:08.890 UTC [81] FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership

You are probably running the docker on a Windows machine? If so, it seems to be a common bug - [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55110235). So, you might want to use a persistent docker volume instead, a la

```yaml
services:
  emasa-postgres:
    ...
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
    - postgres-compose-network

volumes:
  pgdata:
```

> I still have doubts about my compose which localhost to use in pgadmin

In order to connect to your `emasa-postgres` from `pgadmin`, you can set the hostname and network alias for the `emasa-postgres` container like so:

```yaml
services:
    emasa-postgres:
        hostname: my_super_cool_postgres
        image: postgres
        networks:
            postgres-compose-network:
                aliases:
                    - my_super_cool_postgres
```

Instead of using `localhost` or `db` you should then be able to connect to the database via the host `my_super_cool_postgres`.

This way, you should be able to connect to your postgres container from pgadmin. If it still doesn't work for you, you can also try using the [links](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links) instead, which is a legacy feature of Docker, but should work, e.g.

```yaml
services:
    teste-pgadmin-compose:
        image: dpage/pgadmin4
        links:
            - "emasa-postgres:my_super_cool_postgres"
```

This time, you have to set it for the `teste-pgadmin-compose` (or from wherever you need to access to the `emasa-postgres` container). The host `my_super_cool_postgres` and port `5432` should then be accessible.

Comment: This seems to solve, the error msg of the log is gone, but I still have doubts about my compose which localhost to use in pgadmin

Answer (score 1):

**Your** containers are part of a **bridge** network for automatic **DNS** resolution as you defined in the `docker-compose.yml` and use `postgres-compose-network` wich you defined to be a **bridge**

```
networks:
  postgres-compose-network:
    driver: bridge
```

**Try** this :

1. **Run** `docker network ls` to find out the networks created in your docker runtime all networks will be listed in the console, you will find a `[name]_default` something like `name-of-project-directory_default` this should be your network.
2. **Next run** `docker network inspect [name]_default` to inspect the network, it will print something like this :

   ```
   [
   {
       "Name": "dockerizing_default",
       "Id": "98f8a8ef5153fbe91acc28ed0688179f75e08b321b72aab0abe7bf57e1880cc8",
       "Created": "2020-03-07T14:13:49.446907044+01:00",
       "Scope": "local",
       "Driver": "bridge",
       "EnableIPv6": false,
       "IPAM": {
           "Driver": "default",
           "Options": null,
           "Config": [
               {
                   "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                   "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
               }
           ]
       },
       "Internal": false,
       "Attachable": true,
       "Ingress": false,
       "ConfigFrom": {
           "Network": ""
       },
       "ConfigOnly": false,
       "Containers": {},
       "Options": {},
       "Labels": {
           "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
           "com.docker.compose.project": "dockerizing",
           "com.docker.compose.version": "1.25.4"
       }
   }
   ]
   ```
3. **find** the `IPv4Address` , you should be using this ip address instead of `localhost` , it could be `172.18.0.2` 
   I hope this will solve the issue

Comment: i try with this and got this: Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "172.22.0.3" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: Even when using "bridge" driver, `EXPOSE`d ports are still mapped to the host. localhost will always work (unless you are running Docker in a VM), but when using bridge driver, the port may *additionally* be available externally

Comment: yeah maybe that's bcoz you set the database to be `POSTGRES_DB: emasa` in `docker-compose.yaml` but you are using `postgres` on pgadmin web interface either update docker compose to use postgres or use emasa as name of db when connecting : like `host 172.22.0.3 , password amasa@ , db emasa`

Answer (score 0):

Try hostname is `127.0.0.1:4532`.
Also make sure postgres container running use
`docker ps`

**UPDATE:**
This should be worked

```
volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
ports:
    - "5432:5432"
environment:
    PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
```

Comment: i try this but dont work and try docker ps and got: CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                            NAMES
30fb3ec688dd        emasa-web           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:4000->4000/tcp           back-end_web_1
87bd9318c4c9        dpage/pgadmin4      "/entrypoint.sh"         About a minute ago   Up About a minute   443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:16543->80/tcp   back-end_teste-pgadmin-compose_1

Answer (score 0):

it’s not db, change this "host": "db"

To this

"host": "emasa-postgres”

emasa-postgres is the name you use instead of the ip address for the connection between services

Change that in your orm config

Comment: I changed that, but regarding my pgadmin it remains the same way to connect